# Looping and finding similar number in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA. Just started reading it up 2 days ago. I am wondering how could I write a VB codes assigned to a button to read through the whole column and search for similar numbers.

After that identifying similar numbers, it would need to move on to another column to check if the character in the column are same too.

If both of the logic = true . How can i change the cell of the value of another column?

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci5cP.png)

For the current example. The code should know that the first column had matching numbers. After that it will check for the name which is "a" in the example. After that it will automatically change the point to 1 and 0. If there are 3 same ones it will be 1,0,0 for the point

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: yes that is possible.

Comment: @serakfalcon could you give me a sample of how it should look like?

Comment: @muffi Have not started on this . I do not know how to start on it. lol

Comment: Enable to Developer Tab on Excel. Do some homework on the Workbook and WorkSheet objects. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-object-excel, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel etc.

Comment: If there is a value occurring multiple times say thrice, then does the second and third occurrences needs to matched with first? What if they match or don't match. Any sample data will be helpful.

Comment: @Mrig Provided with a sample data!

Comment: What's `1` and  `0`?

Comment: @Mrig It is a point system. If there is duplicate ID, then the point would be set at 1 only. However if the duplicate account participate 4 times the score would be 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per image attached in image I am assuming numbers are in `Column A`, column to check characters is `Column J` and result needs to be displayed in `Column O` then try following code.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, fCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, temp As Long
    Dim c1

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")      'change Sheet2 to your data sheet

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'last row with data in Column A

        c1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        For i = UBound(c1, 1) To 1 Step -1          'enter unique values with corresponding values in dict1
            dict1(c1(i, 1)) = .Range("J" & i + 1)   '+1 for Row 2
        Next i

        Set fCell = .Range("A2")
        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)    'loop through each cell in Column A
            temp = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(fCell, cel.Address), cel)   'get count
            If temp > 1 Then
                If cel.Offset(0, 9) = dict1(cel.Value) Then
                    cel.Offset(0, 14).Value = 0
                Else
                    cel.Offset(0, 14).Value = 1
                End If
            Else
                cel.Offset(0, 14).Value = 1
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'change Sheet3 to your data range

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'last row with data in Column A

        .Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($J$2:$J2=J2)),3)=1,1,0)"   'enter formula in Cell O2
        .Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("O2:O" & lastRow)                'drag formula down
        .Range("O2:O" & lastRow).Value = .Range("O2:O" & lastRow).Value           'keep only values
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! What I was trying to say that If Col A matches = true, then Col J also matches = true. Then the value of the second matching number would be 0. @Mrig

Comment: @user7334325 - `second matching number would be 0` means `Column A` or `Column J`?

Comment: For example col A data : 1,1,2,3,4,5,10,21
For example col J data : a,a,b,c,d,e,g,z
Col O should display data: 1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1

Means that if column A have duplicate data , and also the data in Col J is also duplicated means that under Col O, the score should be 1 , 0

If Col A have duplicate data, but under Col J, they are different, Col O should show 1,1

@Mrig

Comment: @user7334325 - I guess this is what my code does. Are you getting incorrect result? if yes can you please share.

Comment: Ohh I know why. It's because for my thing to work, it should be if there is duplicate of 3 from column A . Then result would be 1,0,0. However if there is duplicate of 4 from column A. Result would need to be 1,0,0,1.. Then 5 from column A. It should be 1,0,0,1,0 and go on repeating the same loop.

Comment: YOU DA BEST OMG! I am gonna read on your code on how did you manage to do it out! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You may try recording whatever you want to do with record macros first, then filter out the codes that are not necessary. If you do not know how to record it using macros, click on the link below. You can learn from the recorded macros and slowly improvise your codes in the future from the experience you may gain.

Here's [a link] (http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-record-a-macro-in-excel-2016/)

Comment: since you're new to vba, just try recording and you can try pressing "f8" to run the code line by line to see which line does what. Then learn from the lines, as that's what i did when i first lean about vba as well.